# How do I temporarily store input from unregistered user in Django?

Tags: django

I would like a user to input their postal address (or zip code) so I can present them with localized information for the duration they are on the site. I only want to save their address if they take a future action that requires a new database entry. Since I only care about holding onto the address during their current visit, I think maybe this would have something to do with extending sessions in Django? Is this the best way to go about it? Are sessions a secure way of temporarily storing an address?

Suggested resources and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"holding onto the address during their current visit" - that's right what sessions are for. It's secure enough for this purpose, you can even encrypt it if you like. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions) contains everything you need to do this, it's not difficult.